# How to acquire or generate test data for a recommender system

Tags: testing, system, mahout, test-data

I'm currently researching [recommender systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system) and would like to know how other researchers acquire or generate test data to evaluate the systems' performance?

Answer (score 8):

When I was working with Recommender Systems I had the exact same problem. I enjoyed the Grouplens dataset the most:

http://grouplens.org/node/12

You can download ratings given by users to movies.

Also, I described in my blog some datasets I found while researching:

http://girlincomputerscience.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/datasets.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what field you're evaluating, but if it's movie recommendations, you could use the [MovieLens data](http://grouplens.org) from [GroupLens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GroupLens_Research) to start out with. (It seems like their site is temporarily down, but I'm sure it will be back up soon).

They have three sets of data - 100,000 votes (preferences), 1 million, and 10 million - and it seems like they're more or less the standard that everyone starts out with.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the info. What if people were looking for a data set that was item based rather than rating based? E.G. Collaborative filtering vs contentfiltering/itemfiltering/info retrieval.

Comment: What do you mean? The Grouplens set can be used for collaborative filtering, too.